# move all dependent libraries to a folder in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have downloaded a few libraries for my netbeans solution to work.
I want to store these in a seperate folder so when I save to GIT, I can checkout my project at home at not have to redownload all the libs it references.

Can I do this if I already have my project up and running?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, yes; NetBeans will use the libraries you specify in your project. You might also look at this related question, [*How to use .jar files in NetBeans?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans/1976322#1976322)