# Dealing with Excel files

Tags: java, excel

I want to read ms-excel file in java and I've also downloaded the compressed file containing 'poi' api by Apache( on the site http://jakarta.apache.org/poi) but where actually to unzip it? means in which path?? whether in org.Apache or somewhere else??

Comment: 7 Questions over the past month, and you have not **accepted a single answer**.   This is poor SOtiquette.  People are less likely to answer your questions.  Please think on this.

Comment: Also, please learn to spell.  (or at least to spell-check)

Comment: Thank You Sir, actually I've accepted the answers but not marked but I'll make it a point that such thing won't happen ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just unpacked it in the same directory as my NetBeans project and created a library as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans/1976322).

Addendum: Download the preferred file from [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) and unzip it in a convenient place such as your project directory. I added `poi-3.6-20091214.jar` as a new library from my NetBeans project directory.

```
$ ls -1
build
build.xml
manifest.mf
nbproject
poi-3.6
src
test
test.xls
```

Building form the command line is straightforward, too.

```
$ javac \
  -cp poi-3.6/poi-3.6-20091214.jar \
  -d build/classes \
  -sourcepath src \
  src/POIExcelReader.java
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I want the specific description about where to download the 'poi' package!! :)

Comment: IUUC, you already have the POI archive file and you've unzipped it. Now just put `poi-3.6-20091214.jar` on the classpath, as suggested above.

Comment: Thank you sir!:)
 I tried to do so but couldn't work! :( 
Actually, I unzipped it one of my folders(D:\My Documents\Supria\Softwares) and then I tried to set the classpath using 'control panel' on the windows xp as 'D:\My Documents\Supria\Softwares\poi-3.6\poi-3.6-20091214.jar', but then too its not working. What can be the reason? I'm getting error as "package 'org.apache.poi.usermodel' doesn't exist", Can you please suggest?