# Netbeans: Is it possible to use newer version of JUnit than the bundeled one?

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, junit

Has anyone tried to use a newer version of JUnit in Netbeans? Netbeans currently has 4.5 bundled. Newest is 4.8 or so.

Could a newer version of JUnit break compatibility with Netbeans' unit test integration? Or do something else negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans/1976322#1976322) the new `Junit` JAR as a library and then add it to the project's `Test Libraries` folder in the `Projects` window. The `Test Libraries` folder is below the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans/1975994#1975994).