# Is there a way to make Junit3 the default Test Runner in Eclipse 3.4.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

We have been supporting a legacy project that requires the use of Java 1.4, and during  development of test suites in Eclipse 3.4.0 it is pretty cumbersome to have to set each test's default runner to Junit3 manually. I am aware that it is possible to use different JVM's while running automated build scripts that launch the test suites, but this particular annoyance happens during development, when you're 'testing the tests' one by one, so to say.

I have been trying to find a way to make JUnit3 the default runner for this version of Eclipse to no avail. Is the only solution to use an older version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to reference and enable the desired version in the Preferences > Java > Junit dialog. Here's a similar [approach for NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209349/netbeans-is-it-possible-to-use-newer-version-of-junit-than-the-bundeled-one).