# sHow do I add external JAR files in a Web Free Form Application in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, red5, netbeans6.8

I have a Red5 application that i want to work on using NetBeans 6.8.

I know I  can use a web Free-Form Application, the only problem that I'm having is to add external `jar` files.

When I go to the project's properties, Where exactly do I add the external jars that I need in order to properly compile the application?

## update

i think that the following URL addresses my problem but i can't really understand the solution.

http://www.bradmcevoy.com/blogs/netbeans_ant_ivy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally resolved the issue by re-creating the project using the step by step tutorial in the following URL : http://blogs.oracle.com/coreqa/entry/setting_up_freeform_project_correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can add the external libraries to your project's `Libraries` folder, or you can add them in the NetBeans' `Tools > Libraries` dialog. The latter can be shared among several projects. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans/1976322) includes illustrations.

Addendum: For free-form type projects, the `Projects > Properties` mentions, "Any settings modified on this panel are for IDE purpose only and do not change the build script. If you want to make changes in build process, please modify your build script manually."

Comment: Hi. When i create web Free-Form application i do not have a libraries folder that is related to my project. When i go to Tools -> Libraries and add the missing jars, it doesn't affect the project. i still get 'does not exist' error on the relevant classes.

Comment: I see what you mean. The link you cited looks like a way to add your custom classpath to `nbproject/project.xml` as a properties file.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution here but it's probably for a lower version of netbeans:

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=5329

i get an error on the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a free-form project, you have to make sure that your build script puts the correct jars into the compile-time classpath. You also want to make your Netbeans project libraries match for auto-complete purposes and error highlighting and such (ie when you view Project Properties->Java Sources ClassPath).