# build maven project with propriatery libraries included

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

How to create maven pom, which will make project buildable, can I include propriatery jars with my project directly without having to take them from repository? anyone did this before ?

EDIT :

I don't want to make it runnable by building assembly with dependencies jar, I want it to be buildable. So anyone having this project is able to build it, even if jars are nowhere to be found at any repository.

Comment: If your libs are updated or extended on occasion see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670812/1744774) to [I want to load all JARs from my libs project folder with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48665906/1744774) for a "pomified" way and such avoiding an additional repo folder and cumbersome cmd lines or `install-file` scripts.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**1** Either you can include that jar in your classpath of application
**2** you can install particular jar file in your maven reopos by

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Comment: life.java how can I do that(#1 sounds interesting)? Can I put my propriatery jars in src/main/resources ? How can I reference that in my pom ?

Comment: @London for one you there is no POM in scene, you simply will have to put jar in classpath of your project you can do it by writing an ant task that will copy your jar to `WEB-INF/lib` .

Comment: This approach is not suitable for a team of developers -- only for a one-man band.

Comment: @01es Approch one is suitable for team , and for 2 each one has to do it once. +1 to your approch, but I feel for a single jar it would be too much to do with your way

Comment: There's an analogous solution that depends on you having a local repository manager like Nexus around.  It involves using `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to push the library to the repository where it would then be available to all developers.

Answer (score 42):

Possible solutions is put your dependencies in src/main/resources then in your pom :

```
<dependency>
groupId ...
artifactId ...
version ...
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Note: system dependencies are not copied into resulted jar/war
(see [How to include system dependencies in war built using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065666/how-to-include-system-dependencies-in-war-built-using-maven))

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Here follows error message: `dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for groupId:yourJar:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects`

Comment: +1 Solution works for me, so it is not a general issue.

Comment: [`<scope>system`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) is deprecated now.

Answer (score 25):

Create a repository folder under your project. Let's take

```
${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/repo
```

Then, install your custom jar to this repo:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=[FILE_PATH] \
-DgroupId=[GROUP] -DartifactId=[ARTIFACT] -Dversion=[VERS] \ 
-Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=[REPO_DIR]
```

Lastly, add the following repo and dependency definitions to the projects pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project-repo</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>[GROUP]</groupId>
        <artifactId>[ARTIFACT]</artifactId>
        <version>[VERS]</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I used the same technique but with `mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=[GROUP] -DartifactId=[ARTIFACT] -Dversion=[VERS] -Durl=file:src/main/resources/repo/ -DrepositoryId=project-repo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=[FILE_PATH]`. You can [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36602391/535203)

Comment: I am trying to do this, but my settings still point to coprorate artifactory and it ignores the local repo

Answer (score 7):

Why not run something like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org), your own maven repo that you can upload 3rd party proprietary jar files, and also proxy other public repositories, to save on bandwith?

[This](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/repoman-sect-reasons.html) also has some good reasons to run your own maven repository manager.

Comment: A repo manager like Nexus is justified when you have a team using maven. For just one developer, make no sense to me.

Comment: Nexus is so easy to set up, that it does make sense to me. I have my own nexus for my research projects because I am tired of always manually installing jars.

Answer (score 7):

You can get it from your local driver as below:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: [`<scope>system`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) is deprecated now.

Answer (score 6):

The really quick and dirty way is to point to a local file:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>sampleGroupId</groupId>  
       <artifactId>sampleArtifactId</artifactId>  
       <version>1.0</version> 
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>C:\DEV\myfunnylib\yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

However this will only live on your machine (obviously), for sharing it usually makes sense to use a proper m2 archive (nexus/artifactory) or if you do not have any of these or don't want to set one up a local maven structured archive and configure a "repository" in your pom:

local:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-local-repo</id>
        <url>file://C:/DEV//mymvnrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

remote:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-remote-repo</id>
        <url>http://192.168.0.1/whatever/mavenserver/youwant/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: [`<scope>system`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) is deprecated now.

Comment: like I wrote "quick and dirty", so deprecated for a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to achieve this is to have a Maven mirror server such as [Sonatype Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/). It is free and very easy to setup (Java web app). With Nexus one can have private (team, corporate etc) repository with a capability of deploying third party and internal apps into it, while also registering other Maven repositories as part of the same server. This way the local Maven settings would reference only the one private Nexus server and all the dependencies will be resolved using it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new folder, let's say `local-maven-repo` at the root of your Maven project.

Just add a local repo iside your `<project>` of your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then for each external jar you want to install, go at the root of your project and execute:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=[GROUP] -DartifactId=[ARTIFACT] -Dversion=[VERS] -Durl=file:./local-maven-repo/ -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=[FILE_PATH]
```

(Copied from [my reply on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602256/535203))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) and create a jar with all dependencies included.

Comment: this is not what I'm asking , I don't want it to be runnable, I want it to be buildable and runable. If I sent you my project, you wouldn't be able to build it because you don't have my propriatery libs and the project uses it. However if I sent you assembly jar , you'd be able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You could either add the jar to your project and mess around with the maven-assembly-plugin, or  add the jar to your local repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging> -DgeneratePom=true

Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
       <group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
       <artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
       <version>       the version of the file
       <packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

Comment: this is not really the answer I'm looking for, Imagine this : you download my project and you can build it, without any interaction from your side appart mvn clean install command

Comment: @London  Thanks for the clarification.  I think I understand now.  
AFAIK, the folder src/main/resources WILL end up on project classpath, but jars therein will not be enumerated on path.  I vaguely recall configuring a project with "internal jars" but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "right" solution here is to add your proprietary libraries to your own repository. It should be simple: create pom for your library project and publish the compiled version on your repository. Add this repository to the list of repositories for your mail project and run build. I believe it will work for you.

Comment: He specified: "So anyone having this project is able to build it, even if jars are nowhere to be found at any repository." and also "without having to take them from repository". I have no idea why maven people love the idea of public repositories so much :)