# How to Include specific jars in WAR, WEB-INF/lib directory with maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

This is my pom.xml, trying to create a WAR file with specific 3 libraries in WEB-INF/lib directory.

I include them in `<packagingIncludes>` tag and the they are packaged in lib dir,  but all `.class` files are ignored.

I cannot use `<packagingExcludes>` because the dependent project has many 3rd party jars and out of my control.

what is wrong here or is there a way i can ignore all jars except 3 specific jars?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>1.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>frmId</groupId>
    <artifactId>frm</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>frmw</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/frm-fl*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/frm-bean*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/frm-facade-${ffm.fpi.version}.jar</packagingIncludes>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>${maven-sca-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fi.ps</groupId>
        <artifactId>frmc-fl</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to put your 3 specific libraries as dependencies of the project and maven will put it on WEB-INF/lib during package phase

**Update:**

To exclude JAR comming from dependencies you have to use this kind of syntax

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

And to exclude all sub dependencies (maven 3 only):

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

**Update 2**

with maven-war-plugin you should add WEB-INF/classes/** to packagingIncludes

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/frm-fl*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/frm-bean*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/frm-facade-${ffm.fpi.version}.jar,WEB-INF/classes/**></packagingIncludes>
         <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I tried that. As I said the dependencies have internal huge list dependencies and all those jars would come into lib folder. Which i do not want.

Comment: I edit my answer to explain how to exclude sub dependencies

Comment: If I ignore sub dependencies then I have compilation issues.

Comment: If you need some jar during the compilation but not on the final war you have to use <scope>provided</scope> on the jar

Comment: I donot have the control of those jars. It varies from the version of dependent project i use and it is huge list to use <scope>. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: Ok I understand. I can't try but I think if you should add WEB-INF/classes/* to packagingIncludes in order to have all class file. I update my answer

Comment: Thanks. But WEB-INF/classes/* did not help. Just the folder was added not the .class files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95549/discussion-between-kuroro-and-rajath).

Comment: Answer is in the chat. I updated my answer. Can you mark the answer as accep please ?