# How can add the proprietary library in maven project with dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a proprietary library. I am using this library in my java desktop project but now, I have a maven project. I want to add this library in my maven project with dependency. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate [build maven project with propriatery libraries included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491199/build-maven-project-with-propriatery-libraries-included).

Comment: Install it in your repository and depend on it. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should search if this library is available as maven dependency. Try **[maven search](http://search.maven.org/).**

For example if you want to include a library commons-io-2.4.jar, you serach for it in the link above, if it is in public repository (it is), then you get maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

You should paste this dependency to your pom to  dependencies tag.

If above library is not available in public repository, you have to place your jar manually in your local repository by refering to: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Example:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-io -DartifactId=commons-io -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=2.4 -Dfile=home_folder_path/commons-io-2.4.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I show this answer another web site before but i do not understand. Can you explain this a little more please?

Comment: Edited my previos response to give you an example.

Comment: Thank you it is working. But i have another library about OCR. And it has two .dll files. I must specify this .dll files for working. And not only two .dll files, it has another config files about Turkish Character Configuration. How can i add this library in my project?

Comment: You can add dll dependencies jut the same as you add jar dependencies. To the dependency tag you have to add a type tag: <type>dll</type>

Answer (score 0):

If it is not already on maven repository, simply add it to your pom.xml, and add it to your local repository.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.proppath</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylib.jar</artifactId>
        <version>myjarversion</version>
    </dependency>
```

And also put this prop library into 
   .m2\repository\com\proppath\myjarversion

Give any groupId you like but make sure that you have corresponding path on repository to find it.

Normally, in large projets these kind of propriatery libraries are stored in Nexus of your enterprise.