# I want to load all JARs from my libs project folder with Maven

Tags: java, maven, deployment, build, dependencies

I have a Java project using Maven. In my project I have a folder called `libs` that contains all the JARs that I can't load from internet/external repository.

My issue is how to specify to Maven to include those JARs during packaging, building etc.?

New to Maven, sorry if it is a stupid question.

EDIT : I have an automatic tool that will look up at my `pom.xml` on my Git to build & deploy my project on different environments. So adding it in local Maven repo, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) will not help since it will work only on my PC. If I add a `libs` folder with my JARs it will work wherever I am.

Ask me in comments if it's not clear or if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)

Comment: This is not a job that Maven should do. Just include these JARs in your classpath.

Comment: @Generic this will add local JARs into your maven local repository but that's not what I want to do here.

Comment: @Mick I agree, but then for example I put my code on GIT with my extern JARs in lib, if someone take the code he'll have to set the classpath again right ? I have a automatic tool that use Maven to build&deploy my project, setting the  classpath will be good only on local using Eclipse if I'm not wrong ?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4491469/5006866, or better https://stackoverflow.com/a/29272852/5006866

Comment: @thokuest Re your first link: [`<scope>system`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) is deprecated.

Comment: @LoganWlv: just work with relative file paths and you will be fine (?)

Comment: @Mick hmm not sure about what you mean

Comment: @Mick Re "_This is not a job that Maven should do. Just include these JARs in your classpath._" – Can it be that Maven builds up a classpath at `compile` and `testCompile` from its local repository, depending on the POM's dependency declarations, behind the scenes? Did you ever run a `mvn compile -X`? If yes, have you ever seen the property`classpathElements` there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to your EDIT adding to the local Maven repo *will* help and it can be automated as follows:

- See [jtahlborn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803426/1744774) to [Multiple install:install-file in a single pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803426/1744774). (The current version of the `maven-install-plugin` is `2.5.2`. I'd use that rather than the default.)
- The `<configuration>`s should look like:

  ```
    <configuration>
      <file>${project.basedir}/path/to/your/libs/lib-X.jar</file>
      <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>

      <!-- match the dependency declaration for this artifact -->
      <groupId>logan.wlv</groupId>
      <artifactId>lib-X</artifactId>
      <version>x.y.z</version> 
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <!-- -------------------------------------------------- -->
    </configuration>
  ```
- Put the `install-plugin` declaration into a [build profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803426/1744774), e.g. `lib`.
- Run `mvn initialize -P lib` once on every new PC (and once after the contents of `libs`, and hence the `install-plugin` declaration, changed) before invoking any phase that resolves dependencies first, e.g. `compile`.

or

- Automate this even further with:

  ```
    <profile>
      <id>lib</id>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <missing>${settings.localRepository}/logan/wlv/lib-X/x.y.z/lib-X-x.y.z.jar</missing>
        </file>
      </activation>
      ...
    <profile>
  ```

  Such being able to run just `mvn initialize` without the explicit profile activation the very first time.

Comment: You know that `<settings><LocalRepository>...` may point elsewhere?

Comment: Also a shell script doing the `install:install-file` commands once on every new PC is quite similar to running `mvn initialize -P lib` once on every new PC.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know. Though not very common to be changed from the default (_Convention over configuration!_ ;) you're right. `${settings.localRepository}` should  work (I never used or tried that) too and is more generic. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What's the point of introducing an extra script file that contains [all the `install-file` arguments](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html#The_install:install-file_goal) compared to having all the relevant information in the very same POM and being able to execute it with a well-known `mvn ...` command?