# How to make .jar library from sources

Tags: java, android

I have Tapjoy sources sources, which have such sructure: `Tapjoy/src/com/tapjoy/*.class`

It must be compiled with Android API Level 9 and higher.
My project is in version Android API Level 8.

So I need to make from sources of `Tapjoy -> tapjoy.jar` file and include it to my main project.

How can I make `.jar` file properly with command line or from eclipse?

Comment: If Tapjoy requires API Level 9, it's very likely that you will not be able to complile with API Level 8, because some required symbols will not be present.  Just recompiling from source doesn't help if a certain required functionality isn't present.

Comment: Thanks all for help, I checked out the most appropriate answer, and will write details as soon as possible to help avoid problems for other developers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or from command line

```
jar cvf tapjoy.jar Tapjoy.class
```

Comment: I put it to D:\  , the classes in com.tapjoy.*.class.    After that I used cmd: "jar cvf tapjoy.jar com"  And it have included all classes in tapjoy.jar file. But when I connected it to eclipse project - It don't see these files((

Comment: How are you importing the jar into your project?  You might have to add it to the class path also.

Project -> Properties -> Java build path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars.
Browse for the jar and click Finish

Answer (score 8):

In Eclipse IDE, it's very easy to create a JAR file.

Just right click on your package > Export > Java > JAR File (and follow the wizard!)

Comment: I know this, but when I am adding Tapjoy to project it prompts many errors. How to connect it properly?

Answer (score 1):

both are possible

you can also use ant or maven for this kind of functionality.

check for the [jar tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html) for commandline approach!

check [eclipse ant build](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t65486.html) for eclipse approach and check the [ant jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) for ant approach

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans IDE, you can easy create own jar library,

Projects on Right click -> Clean and build

Thats it. You can use it now your **"Project Location"/dist/MyApplication.jar**

All you need to do create new project and import your jar file [How to import Jar File ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975994/3129822)