# Adding CLASSPATH in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

I need to add classpath in `NetBeans`. I'm reading book **"Thinking in Java 4th Edition"**.

From doc:

> "In the Projects window, right-click the project node and choose Properties.
>   Click Libraries in the left panel of the Project Properties dialog box.
>   Adding library path in the right panel."

I did that, but when I wrote : *import static net.mindview.util.print.** 
I see next:*package net does not exist*

Help.  Why package does not exist?

Comment: What exactly did you add to the project libraries?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [How to use .jar files in NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans), which has some helpful illustrations.

Comment: And when i add this folder i see that in my project - library. I see folder and if i press "+" . I will see many yellow boxes. Example: " net.mindview.util" , "net", ...

Answer (score 1):

I recently added a classpath for Java mysql-connector in Netbeans. This may help someone who has been struggling to do it like me

1. have the connector in your computer downloaded, for my case I downloaded from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
2. Right click on your project in the projects window as shown here
   [image for right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI6jM.png)
3. On the dialog window click on Libraries, then click Add jar/folder. Make sure the check box (Build projects on class path) is checked.
4. Select your connector/ jar file you want in your case. Then Click open.
5. It will be appended in the dialog box as shown below.
   [image for dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbN0X.png)

click OK