# No suitable driver found exception thrown, Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

The error in the title is what I'm facing. I've searched on multiple posts, but each and every one of them mentions bad classpaths, or .jar inputs.

```
try(java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/guestbook", "root", "");){
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("select username, text from impression");
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            
            while(rs.next()){
                all_impressions.append(rs.getString("username"));
                all_impressions.append(": ");
                all_impressions.append(rs.getString("text"));
                all_impressions.append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
           all_impressions.append(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

It throws me the exception that I append to `all_impressions` every time, and I'm trying to load table content from SQL database. Also, I am using Spring MVC framework if it matters.

EDIT: mysql-connector jar is added to the classpath, and yet I still have the same issue.

EDIT: Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/guestbook
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at model.Impression.allImpressions(Impression.java:54)
    at controller.ImpressionController.createForm(ImpressionController.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: add the mysql-connector jar to your classpath

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you link me how to do that?

Comment: it depends on how you are running your application.

Comment: NetBeans IDE 8.0

Comment: [Amazing what a quick search will find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708330/adding-classpath-in-netbeans)

Comment: I have added the mysql-connector to my classpath, and yet it throws me the same error. @ScaryWombat

Comment: Change `all_impressions.append(ex.getMessage());` to `ex.printStackTrace()` and then edit your question showing the stacktrace.

Comment: I just changed it. It seems that it's the same stacktrace as glassfish throws.

Comment: **new information** - you are using glassfish.  Search to see how to edit classpath for glassfish

Comment: I've added mysql-connector both to IDE classpath and to glassfish/glassfish/lib. Still the same error.

Comment: OK, what version of the jar are you using? What JDK version are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.8, GlassFish 4.1.1, mysql-connector-java-5.1.34_1

Comment: `jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306` -> `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306`

Comment: Oh my god.. What a dumb error... However, I get a new error, but I'll seek the solution by myself. Thank you so much, and good luck! :)

Comment: Not so easy to spot.