# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jdbc.mysql.Driver occuring even after adding java connector jar file

Tags: java, mysql, classnotfoundexception, netbeans-8, mysql-connector

I am trying to add some input to my mysql table using java in netbeans.

Ive added the required connector file as you can see in the library section.
[image: Ive added the Connector jar file as you can see]

But even after adding the connector jar file it throws the exception. Pls help me to resolve this.

[image: err]

Comment: I guess that just adds it to the buildpath.  You need to add it to the classpath as well.

Comment: Can you please suggest me on how to do that.

Comment: Open a web browser and type "NetBeans - how to add jar to classpath" Oh look what I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708330/adding-classpath-in-netbeans