# Adding components to the palette in NetBeans GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have created some custom `JPanel` classes using the NetBeans GUI Builder. Next, I added them to the palette. Then I created a custom `JFrame` and was able to drag my `JPanel`s onto the `JFrame`. This worked great while I was simply working on the GUI front end. Now I am working on the backend logic, which includes some JDBC code. I have created a `BaseballCardIO` interface and implemented it in `BaseballCardJDBCIO` to centralize all the the database stuff.

Now, one of my JPanels, `AddCardsPanel`, needs a reference to one of these `BaseballCardIO`s. I started by creating one directly in the `AddCardsPanel` constructor. (I know, not the best design decision anyway...) Everything was working great until I open my `JFrame` class in NetBeans. It started to complain about not finding the JDBC driver class.

I want to continue to use the NetBeans GUI Builder for now. I have two solutions in mind to fix my problem:

1) Tell NetBeans where to find the JDBC driver and keep the code as-is. How do I do this?

2) Modify my design so that `AddCardsPanel` has a constructor which takes a `BaseballCardIO` as a parameter. This would actually be preferrable since it makes more sense for someone else to be responsible for creating the `BaseballCardIO`, not `AddCardsPanel`. However, I still need `AddCardsPanel` to play nicely with NetBeans GUI Builder, which means that it needs a no-args constructor. I imagine that I could add some code which detects if `AddCardsPanel` is being used as a JavaBean by NetBeans then the `JFrame` calls the noargs constructor. Otherwise, if my application is actually running, then the `JFrame` calls other constructor and sends it a `BaseballCardIO`.

Is this a good way to go? Or does anyone have any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the driver JAR to NetBeans as a library, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976322/230513), and to your project, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975994/230513).
2. In `Window > Services > Database > New Connections`, fill out the required fields.
3. Don't let the NetBeans GUI builder dictate your design. Isolate database access to your `TableModel` and other component models.
4. Edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows any problems you encounter; a .`form` should *not* be required.

Comment: I already added the JAR file to my project's libraries. I didn't know about adding it separately to NetBeans. Thanks!

Comment: Good; you might try this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513) to taming the GUI designer.

Comment: I revisited my design. It's pretty ad hoc anyway, since this is a small project. I decided that I want to create my `BaseballCardIO` objects in `main()` and pass them to my `JFrame` and then to the `JPanel`s that need it. I think this will make it easier in future versions to add configuration options so that the user can set up alternative database back-ends or other storage targets.

Comment: I think that's a good plan. You'll want to build a few small components and projects to see how they can be composed into larger ones.