# Error while trying to run a wizard module in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7 and I am trying to run a wizard in it.

The build of the module worked fine, but while trying to run it is showing some error as shown below:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ./build_files/spring-instrument.jar

Error occurred during initialization of VM

agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: How should a demo of Wizard to be run in NetBeans ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really tried it, but make sure whatever library has `spring-instrument.jar` gets added to your project, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1975973/261156). Also, you could go though the [NetBeans Wizard Module Tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-wizard.html) to see if you left any steps out.