# How do I add SteelSeries javadoc in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, api, javadoc, steelseries

I am having trouble getting the steelseries javadoc to work in Netbeans. This is the URL https://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/84552/SteelSeries3/apidocs/index.html but I cannot seem to get it to play ball. Have I missed something obvious?

Thank you

Comment: Please add more details where exactly you stuck, what steps you succeeded, what error message you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Tools > Libraries`, you can create a new library, set the location of your API documentation in the `Javadoc` tab and add the library to your project, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans/1976322#1976322).

[image]
<sub>(source: [netbeans.org](http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/images/d/d4/LibraryManager671.png))</sub>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. That's what I've done in the past, and its worked with Apache POI. However, this particular javadoc doesn't seem to be working. Could it be something to do with it being a dropbox link, or HTTPS? Thanks again!

Comment: I never tried a URL for the `Javadoc` before, but it worked with some limitations: NetBeans defers showing the doc during code completion but opens it correctly in the browser. I didn't try `https`, and I don't use `Dropbox`. Why not just download or generate it locally?

Comment: Hi, I tried using the downloaded page but got an error message: "The javadoc root does not contain the package-list file"

Comment: I'd expect the `package-list` to be in the same directory as the `index.html`, but it may have been generated by a custom `doclet`.

Comment: what exactly is the package-list?

Comment: Hi guys, thank for all your help... In the end I found the .jar javadoc and that seemed to work, thanks again!