# JFreeChart setAutoRange when XYSplineRenderer is used as rendered

Tags: jfreechart

A chart needs to be plotted with smooth shape, so XYSplineRenderer is used.
Also, the NumberAxis needs to be autoranged to the segment of data.

But in some cases when the spline is calculated, some spline values are out of the autorange segment and the curve is not plotted entirely.

[image]

Seems that the autorange is evaluated before the spline is calculated.

To mitigate it, I have adjusted the range of the vertical axis by increasing this range by a percentage of the range limits.  But this leads to inaccurate curve fitting to charts, since depending of the data input the percentage could be up to 25%.

```java
double percentOverRange = 0.05;//2%
double initalRange = series.getMaxY() - series.getMinY();
double increase = initalRange*percentOverRange;
verticalAxis.setRange(new Range(series.getMinY()-increase, series.getMaxY()+increase));
```

This code creates the above picture and demonstrates how the curve is not entirely plotted between the two first data points.
*Note that domain axis is DateAxis (daily data) without values at weekend*

```java
public class MyPlotChart {
    private static Color MetalColor = new Color(255, 152, 0);
    static double[] yData = new double[] { 0.67, 0.67, 0.69, 0.70, 0.70, 0.71, 0.71 };
    static String[] labels = new String[] { "2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-12", "2021-11-15", "2021-11-16", "2021-11-17" };
    public static void plot(String metal, int samples) throws IOException, ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateformatyyyy_MM_dd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat dateformatdd_MM_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(metal);
        for (int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++) {
            Date date = dateformatyyyy_MM_dd.parse(labels[i]);
            series.add(date.getTime(), yData[i]);
        }
        //Configure Vertical Axis
        NumberAxis verticalAxis = new NumberAxis(null);
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        double vericalTickUnit = (series.getMaxY() - series.getMinY()) / 7;
        NumberTickUnit nt = new NumberTickUnit(vericalTickUnit, numberFormat);
        verticalAxis.setTickUnit(nt);
        double percentOverRange = 0.05;// 2%
        double initalRange = series.getMaxY() - series.getMinY();
        double increase = initalRange * percentOverRange;
        verticalAxis.setRange(new Range(series.getMinY()-increase, series.getMaxY()+increase));
        verticalAxis.setAutoRange(true);
        verticalAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        verticalAxis.setTickMarksVisible(true);
        verticalAxis.setTickMarkInsideLength(3f);
        //Configure Domain Axis
        DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis(null);
        domainAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.DAY, 1, dateformatdd_MM_yyyy));
        //Configure Renderer
        XYSplineRenderer r = new XYSplineRenderer(10);
        r.setSeriesPaint(0, MetalColor);
        r.setDefaultShapesVisible(true);
        r.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        XYDataset dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        XYPlot xyplot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, verticalAxis, r);
        xyplot.getDomainAxis().setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        xyplot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
        xyplot.setBackgroundImage(null);
        xyplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        Font font = xyplot.getDomainAxis().getTickLabelFont();
        Font fontnew = new Font(font.getName(), Font.BOLD, 14);
        xyplot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(fontnew);
        xyplot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(fontnew);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(xyplot);
        chart.removeLegend();// Remove legend
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        String fileName = "myChart" + metal + samples + "TEST.png";
        ChartUtils.saveChartAsPNG(new File(fileName), chart, 600, 600);
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        MyPlotChart.plot("metal", 7);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

The following plots are from the code above just changing the precision of the XYSplineRenderer.

As defined in javadoc:

> XYSplineRenderer: A renderer that connects data points with natural
> cubic splines and/or draws shapes at each data point.
>
> public XYSplineRenderer(int precision)
>
> Creates a new renderer with the specified precision and no fill of the
> area 'under' (between '0' and) the spline.
>
> Parameters:
> precision - the number of points between data items.

That means that the natural cubic splines are calculated just based on the data points.

On the other side, the precision is used to define the number of interpolated points between each pair of data points.

*Precision = N - 1, where N = Number of interpolated points between each data point  segment*

I just can see two options:

1. XYSplineRenderer should have a method returning the set of natural cubic splines, so the maximum value of each segment could be calculated and hence the AutoRange could be set accordingly
2. Instead of natural cubic splines, JFreeChart should implement a renderer based on NURBS (Non-uniform rational basis spline), which controls the shape of the curve with a set of Control Points ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline))

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2**

The problem increases when there is not data available (weekends) and the DateAxis inserts two days between Friday and Monday: the gap between values is greater and hence the spline is also longer.

[image]

Comment: @trashgod, I have edited the question with some tests regarding the precision of the XYSplineRenderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [*JFreeChart adding trend-line outside of actual values*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23454262/230513), such anomalies are inevitable for functions that are not strictly monotonic. Absent more detailed spline control, you may get a better result by enabling auto-range on the problematic axis (the default) and adjusting the axis margin empirically.

```
rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true); // true by default
rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.08); // 8% lower margin
```

In the variation below, note the following:

- [`setLowerMargin()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setLowerMargin(double)) decreases the lower margin for the range axis by 8% of the axis range.
- `setNumberFormatOverride()` and `setDateFormatOverride` are used to format the tick labels.
- `XYSplineRenderer` is constructed with an arbitrary `precision` of 15.
- `deriveFont()` is used to change the axis tick label font attributes.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYSplineRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70021577/230513
 */
public class SplineTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatyyyy_MM_dd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat formatdd_MM_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        double[] yData = new double[]{0.67, 0.67, 0.69, 0.70, 0.70, 0.71, 0.71};
        String[] labels = new String[]{"2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-11",
            "2021-11-12", "2021-11-15", "2021-11-16", "2021-11-17"};
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Series");
        for (int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++) {
            Date date = formatyyyy_MM_dd.parse(labels[i]);
            series.add(date.getTime(), yData[i]);
        }
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis(null);
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(numberFormat);
        rangeAxis.setTickMarksVisible(true);
        rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true); // true by default
        rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.08); // 8% lower margin
        rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis(null);
        domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(formatdd_MM_yyyy);
        domainAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        Font font = domainAxis.getTickLabelFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 10);
        domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(font);
        rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(font);
        XYSplineRenderer r = new XYSplineRenderer(15);
        r.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(255, 152, 0));
        r.setDefaultShapesVisible(true);
        r.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        XYDataset dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        XYPlot xyplot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, r);
        xyplot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
        xyplot.setBackgroundImage(null);
        xyplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(null, null, xyplot, false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        ChartUtils.saveChartAsPNG(new File("temp.png"), chart, 400, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: A variation using JavaFX is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70058015/230513).

Comment: I will use `setLowerMargin()` and  `setUpperMargin()`  to adjust margins empirically, but since the app will run as a microservice on a server to generate a set of daily png files automatically, the margin will arise up to 15%.  I still think that the best option is to modify XYSplineRenderer to collect data  from the natural cubic splines, and from there,  determine the maximum of each spline between intervals. This is a time consuming task I will face in future. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can see the appeal of addressing this in the view. Alternatively, does the domain from which the data arises suggest a suitable regression model, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61398612/230513)?

Comment: There is not possibility to use a regression model, since data is daily market prices of several metals.
Probably I will use precision = 1 for the last 7 days charts.
I also edited the question to show the problem with these curves when you have few data and DateAxis includes the days without data (weekends).

Answer (score 2):

Following what It's pointed out in the question, one possible solution is to use a jfreechart renderer based in NURBS or Bezier curves instead of of natural cubic splines.

With Bezier curves It's possible to control how the curve bends arround the points by defining a parameter (tension).

I have cloned jfreechart from github and create a XYBezierRenderer class which extends XYLineAndShapeRenderer with a parameter (tension) to control the bending of the curve.

[image]

The code for XYBezierRenderer class in shwon below:

```java
package org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy;

import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.event.RendererChangeEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.util.GradientPaintTransformer;
import org.jfree.chart.api.RectangleEdge;
import org.jfree.chart.util.StandardGradientPaintTransformer;
import org.jfree.chart.internal.Args;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

/**
 * A renderer that connects data points with Bezier cubic curves and/or
 * draws shapes at each data point.  This renderer is designed for use with
 * the {@link XYPlot} class.
 * <br><br>
 * 
 * @since
 */
public class XYBezierRenderer extends XYLineAndShapeRenderer {

    /**
     * An enumeration of the fill types for the renderer.
     * 
     * @since 1.0.17
     */
    public static enum FillType {
       
        /** No fill. */
        NONE,
        
        /** Fill down to zero. */
        TO_ZERO,
        
        /** Fill to the lower bound. */
        TO_LOWER_BOUND,
        
        /** Fill to the upper bound. */
        TO_UPPER_BOUND
    }
    
    /**
     * Represents state information that applies to a single rendering of
     * a chart.
     */
    public static class XYBezierState extends State {
        
        /** The area to fill under the curve. */
        public GeneralPath fillArea;
        
        /** The points. */
        public List<Point2D> points;
        
        /**
         * Creates a new state instance.
         * 
         * @param info  the plot rendering info. 
         */
        public XYBezierState(PlotRenderingInfo info) {
            super(info);
            this.fillArea = new GeneralPath();
            this.points = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Resolution of splines (number of line segments between points)
     */
    private int precision;
    
    /**
     *  Tension defines how sharply does the curve bends
     */
    private double tension;

    /**
     * A flag that can be set to specify 
     * to fill the area under the spline.
     */
    private FillType fillType;

    private GradientPaintTransformer gradientPaintTransformer;
    
    /**
     * Creates a new instance with the precision attribute defaulting to 5,
     * the tension attribute defaulting to 2  
     * and no fill of the area 'under' the spline.
     */
    public XYBezierRenderer() {
        this(5, 25, FillType.NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new renderer with the specified precision and tension
     * and no fill of the area 'under' (between '0' and) the spline.
     *
     * @param precision  the number of points between data items.
     * @param tension  value to define how sharply the curve bends
     */
    public XYBezierRenderer(int precision, double tension) {
        this(precision, tension ,FillType.NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new renderer with the specified precision
     * and specified fill of the area 'under' (between '0' and) the spline.
     *
     * @param precision  the number of points between data items.
     * @param tension  value to define how sharply the curve bends
     * @param fillType  the type of fill beneath the curve ({@code null} 
     *     not permitted).
     * 
     * @since 1.0.17
     */
    public XYBezierRenderer(int precision, double tension, FillType fillType) {
        super();
        if (precision <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requires precision > 0.");
        }
        if (tension <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requires precision > 0.");
        }
        Args.nullNotPermitted(fillType, "fillType");
        this.precision = precision;
        this.tension = tension;
        this.fillType = fillType;
        this.gradientPaintTransformer = new StandardGradientPaintTransformer();
    }
/**
 * Returns the number of line segments used to approximate the Bezier
 * curve between data points.
 *
 * @return The number of line segments.
 *
 * @see #setPrecision(int)
 */
public int getPrecision() {
    return this.precision;
}

/**
 * Set the resolution of splines and sends a {@link RendererChangeEvent}
 * to all registered listeners.
 *
 * @param p  number of line segments between points (must be &gt; 0).
 *
 * @see #getPrecision()
 */
public void setPrecision(int p) {
    if (p <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requires p > 0.");
    }
    this.precision = p;
    fireChangeEvent();
}

/**
 * Returns the value of the tension which defines how sharply 
 * does the curve bends
 *
 * @return The value of tesion.
 *
 * @see #setTension(double)
 */
public double getTension() {
    return this.tension;
}

/**
 * Set the value of the tension which defines how sharply 
 * does the curve bends and sends a {@link RendererChangeEvent}
 * to all registered listeners.
 *
 * @param t  value of tension (must be &gt; 0).
 *
 * @see #getTension()
 */
public void setTension(double t) {
    if (t <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requires tension > 0.");
    }
    this.tension = t;
    fireChangeEvent();
}

/**
 * Returns the type of fill that the renderer draws beneath the curve.
 *
 * @return The type of fill (never {@code null}).
 *
 * @see #setFillType(FillType) 
 * 
 * @since 1.0.17
 */
public FillType getFillType() {
    return this.fillType;
}

/**
 * Set the fill type and sends a {@link RendererChangeEvent}
 * to all registered listeners.
 *
 * @param fillType   the fill type ({@code null} not permitted).
 *
 * @see #getFillType()
 * 
 * @since 1.0.17
 */
public void setFillType(FillType fillType) {
    this.fillType = fillType;
    fireChangeEvent();
}

/**
 * Returns the gradient paint transformer, or {@code null}.
 * 
 * @return The gradient paint transformer (possibly {@code null}).
 * 
 * @since 1.0.17
 */
public GradientPaintTransformer getGradientPaintTransformer() {
    return this.gradientPaintTransformer;
}

/**
 * Sets the gradient paint transformer and sends a 
 * {@link RendererChangeEvent} to all registered listeners.
 * 
 * @param gpt  the transformer ({@code null} permitted).
 * 
 * @since 1.0.17
 */
public void setGradientPaintTransformer(GradientPaintTransformer gpt) {
    this.gradientPaintTransformer = gpt;
    fireChangeEvent();
}
    
    /**
     * Initialises the renderer.
     * <P>
     * This method will be called before the first item is rendered, giving the
     * renderer an opportunity to initialise any state information it wants to
     * maintain.  The renderer can do nothing if it chooses.
     *
     * @param g2  the graphics device.
     * @param dataArea  the area inside the axes.
     * @param plot  the plot.
     * @param data  the data.
     * @param info  an optional info collection object to return data back to
     *              the caller.
     *
     * @return The renderer state.
     */
    @Override
    public XYItemRendererState initialise(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D dataArea,
            XYPlot plot, XYDataset data, PlotRenderingInfo info) {

        setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true);
        XYBezierState state = new XYBezierState(info);
        state.setProcessVisibleItemsOnly(false);
        return state;
    }
  
    
    /**
     * Draws the item (first pass). This method draws the lines
     * connecting the items. Instead of drawing separate lines,
     * a GeneralPath is constructed and drawn at the end of
     * the series painting.
     *
     * @param g2  the graphics device.
     * @param state  the renderer state.
     * @param plot  the plot (can be used to obtain standard color information
     *              etc).
     * @param dataset  the dataset.
     * @param pass  the pass.
     * @param series  the series index (zero-based).
     * @param item  the item index (zero-based).
     * @param xAxis  the domain axis.
     * @param yAxis  the range axis.
     * @param dataArea  the area within which the data is being drawn.
     */
    @Override
    protected void drawPrimaryLineAsPath(XYItemRendererState state,
            Graphics2D g2, XYPlot plot, XYDataset dataset, int pass,
            int series, int item, ValueAxis xAxis, ValueAxis yAxis,
            Rectangle2D dataArea) {

        XYBezierState s = (XYBezierState) state;
        RectangleEdge xAxisLocation = plot.getDomainAxisEdge();
        RectangleEdge yAxisLocation = plot.getRangeAxisEdge();

        // get the data points
        double x1 = dataset.getXValue(series, item);
        double y1 = dataset.getYValue(series, item);
        double transX1 = xAxis.valueToJava2D(x1, dataArea, xAxisLocation);
        double transY1 = yAxis.valueToJava2D(y1, dataArea, yAxisLocation);

        // Collect points
        if (!Double.isNaN(transX1) && !Double.isNaN(transY1)) {
            Point2D p = plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL 
                ? new Point2D.Float((float) transY1, (float) transX1) 
                : new Point2D.Float((float) transX1, (float) transY1);
            if (!s.points.contains(p))
                s.points.add(p);
        }
        
        if (item == dataset.getItemCount(series) - 1) {     // construct path
            if (s.points.size() > 1) {
                Point2D origin;
                if (this.fillType == FillType.TO_ZERO) {
                    float xz = (float) xAxis.valueToJava2D(0, dataArea, 
                            yAxisLocation);
                    float yz = (float) yAxis.valueToJava2D(0, dataArea, 
                            yAxisLocation);
                    origin = plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL
                            ? new Point2D.Float(yz, xz) 
                            : new Point2D.Float(xz, yz);
                } else if (this.fillType == FillType.TO_LOWER_BOUND) {
                    float xlb = (float) xAxis.valueToJava2D(
                            xAxis.getLowerBound(), dataArea, xAxisLocation);
                    float ylb = (float) yAxis.valueToJava2D(
                            yAxis.getLowerBound(), dataArea, yAxisLocation);
                    origin = plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL
                            ? new Point2D.Float(ylb, xlb) 
                            : new Point2D.Float(xlb, ylb);
                } else {// fillType == TO_UPPER_BOUND
                    float xub = (float) xAxis.valueToJava2D(
                            xAxis.getUpperBound(), dataArea, xAxisLocation);
                    float yub = (float) yAxis.valueToJava2D(
                            yAxis.getUpperBound(), dataArea, yAxisLocation);
                    origin = plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL
                            ? new Point2D.Float(yub, xub)
                            : new Point2D.Float(xub, yub);
                }
                
                // we need at least two points to draw something
                Point2D cp0 = s.points.get(0);
                s.seriesPath.moveTo(cp0.getX(), cp0.getY());
                if (this.fillType != FillType.NONE) {
                    if (plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                        s.fillArea.moveTo(origin.getX(), cp0.getY());
                    } else {
                        s.fillArea.moveTo(cp0.getX(), origin.getY());
                    }
                    s.fillArea.lineTo(cp0.getX(), cp0.getY());
                }
                if (s.points.size() == 2) {
                    // we need at least 3 points to Bezier. Draw simple line
                    // for two points
                    Point2D cp1 = s.points.get(1);
                    if (this.fillType != FillType.NONE) {
                        s.fillArea.lineTo(cp1.getX(), cp1.getY());
                        s.fillArea.lineTo(cp1.getX(), origin.getY());
                        s.fillArea.closePath();
                    }
                    s.seriesPath.lineTo(cp1.getX(), cp1.getY());
                }
                else if (s.points.size() == 3) {
                    Point2D[] pInitial = getInitalPoints(s);
                    pintar(pInitial, s);
                    Point2D[] pFinal = getFinalPoints(s);
                    pintar(pFinal, s);
                    
                }
                else {
                    // construct Bezier curve
                    //System.out.println("Entra en construir curva larga... " +  s.points.size());
                    int np = s.points.size(); // number of points
                    for(int i = 0; i < np - 1; i++) {
                        if(i == 0) {
                            //System.out.println("Entra en i= 0");
                            // 3 points, 2 lines (initial an final Bezier curves
                            Point2D[] initial3Points = new Point2D[3];
                            initial3Points[0] = s.points.get(0);
                            initial3Points[1] = s.points.get(1);
                            initial3Points[2] = s.points.get(2);
                            Point2D[] pInitial = calcSegmentPointsInitial(initial3Points);// TENSION = 1.5
                            pintar(pInitial, s);
                        }
                        if(i == np - 2) {
                            //System.out.println("Entra en i = np - 2");

                            Point2D[] final3Points = new Point2D[4];
                            final3Points[1] = s.points.get(np-3);
                            final3Points[2] = s.points.get(np-2);
                            final3Points[3] = s.points.get(np-1); 
                            //No se define final3Points[4] pq no se usa
                            Point2D[] pFinal = calcSegmentPointsFinal(final3Points);//TENSION = 1.5
                            pintar(pFinal, s);
                        }
                        if ((i != 0) && (i != (np - 2))){
                            Point2D[] original4Points = new Point2D[4];
                            original4Points[0] = s.points.get(i - 1);
                            original4Points[1] = s.points.get(i);
                            original4Points[2] = s.points.get(i + 1);
                            original4Points[3] = s.points.get(i + 2);
                            Point2D[] pMedium = calculateSegmentPoints(original4Points);
                            pintar(pMedium, s);
                        }
                    }                   
                }
                // Add last point @ y=0 for fillPath and close path
                if (this.fillType != FillType.NONE) {
                    if (plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                        s.fillArea.lineTo(origin.getX(), s.points.get(
                                s.points.size() - 1).getY());
                    } else {
                        s.fillArea.lineTo(s.points.get(
                                s.points.size() - 1).getX(), origin.getY());
                    }
                    s.fillArea.closePath();
                }
                // fill under the curve...
                if (this.fillType != FillType.NONE) {
                    Paint fp = getSeriesFillPaint(series);
                    if (this.gradientPaintTransformer != null 
                            && fp instanceof GradientPaint) {
                        GradientPaint gp = this.gradientPaintTransformer
                                .transform((GradientPaint) fp, s.fillArea);
                        g2.setPaint(gp);
                    } else {
                        g2.setPaint(fp);                        
                    }
                    g2.fill(s.fillArea);
                    s.fillArea.reset();
                }
                // then draw the line...
                drawFirstPassShape(g2, pass, series, item, s.seriesPath);
            }
            // reset points vector
            s.points = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    
    private void pintar(Point2D[] segmentPoints, XYBezierState s) {
        double x;
        double y;
        //System.out.println("Precision: " + this.precision);
        for (int t = 0 ; t <= this.precision; t++) {
            double k = (double)t / this.precision;
            double r = 1- k;
                    
            x = Math.pow(r, 3) * segmentPoints[0].getX() + 3 * k * Math.pow(r, 2) * segmentPoints[1].getX()
                    + 3 * Math.pow(k, 2) * (1 - k) * segmentPoints[2].getX() + Math.pow(k, 3) * segmentPoints[3].getX();
            y = Math.pow(r, 3) * segmentPoints[0].getY() + 3 * k * Math.pow(r, 2) * segmentPoints[1].getY()
                    + 3 * Math.pow(k, 2) * (1 - k) * segmentPoints[2].getY() + Math.pow(k, 3) * segmentPoints[3].getY();
            s.seriesPath.lineTo(x, y);
            //System.out.println("Pintar, t = " + t + "\tk = " + k +"\t" + "\tx = " + x + "\ty = " + y);
        }
    }
    
    private Point2D[] getFinalPoints(XYBezierState s) {
        //System.out.println("getinFinalPoints");
        //for(int i = 0; i< s.points.size(); i++) {
        //  Point2D p = s.points.get(i);
        //  System.out.println("Point" + i  + "\tx = " + p.getX() + "\ty = " + p.getY());
        //}
    
        Point2D[] final3Points = new Point2D[4];
        final3Points[1] = s.points.get(0);
        final3Points[2] = s.points.get(1);
        final3Points[3] = s.points.get(2); 
        //No se define final3Points[4] pq no se usa
        Point2D[] pFinal = calcSegmentPointsFinal(final3Points);//TENSION = 1.5
        return pFinal;
    }

    private Point2D[] getInitalPoints(XYBezierState s) {
        //System.out.println("getInitialPoints");
        //for(int i = 0; i< s.points.size(); i++) {
        //  Point2D p = s.points.get(i);
        //  System.out.println("Point" + i  + "\tx = " + p.getX() + "\ty = " + p.getY());
        //}
        // 3 points, 2 lines (initial an final Bezier curves
        Point2D[] initial3Points = new Point2D[3];
        initial3Points[0] = s.points.get(0);
        initial3Points[1] = s.points.get(1);
        initial3Points[2] = s.points.get(2);
        Point2D[] pInitial = calcSegmentPointsInitial(initial3Points);// TENSION = 1.5
        return pInitial;
    }

    private Point2D[] calculateSegmentPoints(Point2D[] original4Points) {
        //System.out.println("calcSegmentPoints");

        double relativeTension = calcRelativetension(original4Points, false, false);
        Point2D[] points = new Point2D[4];
        points[0] = original4Points[1];
        points[3] = original4Points[2];
        //double modulo = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(original4Points[1].getX() - original4Points[2].getX(), 2) + Math.pow(original4Points[1].getY() - original4Points[2].getY(), 2));
        //double tesionRelativa = modulo * tension / 4;
        
        for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            Point2D aux1 = calcUnitaryVector(original4Points[i-1], original4Points[i]);
            Point2D aux2 = calcUnitaryVector(original4Points[i+1], original4Points[i]);
            Point2D aux3 = calcUnitaryVector(aux2, aux1);
            
            double x = original4Points[i].getX() + Math.pow(-1.0, i+1) * tension * aux3.getX();
            double y = original4Points[i].getY() + Math.pow(-1.0, i+1) * tension * aux3.getY();
            points[i] = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        }
        
        return points;
    }
    
    private Point2D[] calcSegmentPointsInitial(Point2D[] original3P) {
        //System.out.println("calcSegmentPointsInitial");

        /*
         * Each segment is defined by its two endpoints and two control points. A
         * control point determines the tangent at the corresponding endpoint.
         */
        Point2D[] points = new Point2D[4];
        points[0] = original3P[0];// Endpoint 1
        points[3] = original3P[1];// Endpoint 2
        // Control point 1
        Point2D auxInitial = calcUnitaryVector(original3P[0], original3P[1]);
        points[1] = original3P[0];// new Point2D.Double(x0, y0);
        // Control point 2
        // Es el mismo vector que el anterior: Point2D aux1 =
        // calcUnitaryVector(original4P[0], original4P[1]);
        Point2D aux2 = calcUnitaryVector(original3P[2], original3P[1]);
        Point2D aux3 = calcUnitaryVector(auxInitial, aux2);
        double relativeTension = calcRelativetension(original3P, true, false);

        double x = original3P[1].getX() + tension * aux3.getX();
        double y = original3P[1].getY() + tension * aux3.getY();
        points[2] = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        //for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //  System.out.println("Point[" + i  + "]\tx = " + points[i].getX() + "\ty = " + points[i].getY());
        //}
        return points;
    }
    
    private Point2D[] calcSegmentPointsFinal(Point2D[] original3P) {
        //System.out.println("calcSegmentPointsFinal");

        /*
         * Each segment is defined by its two endpoints and two control points. A
         * control point determines the tangent at the corresponding endpoint.
         */
        Point2D[] points = new Point2D[4];
        points[0] = original3P[2];// Endpoint 1
        points[3] = original3P[3];// Endpoint 2
        // Control point 2: points[2]
        Point2D auxInitial = calcUnitaryVector(original3P[3], original3P[2]);
        points[2] = original3P[3];// new Point2D.Double(x0, y0);
        // Control point 1
        Point2D aux1 = calcUnitaryVector(original3P[3], original3P[2]);
        Point2D aux2 = calcUnitaryVector(original3P[1], original3P[2]);
        Point2D aux3 = calcUnitaryVector(aux1, aux2);
        double relativeTension = calcRelativetension(original3P, false, true);
        double x = original3P[2].getX() + tension * aux3.getX();
        double y = original3P[2].getY() + tension * aux3.getY();
        points[1] = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        //for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //  System.out.println("Point[" + i  + "]\tx = " + points[i].getX() + "\ty = " + points[i].getY());
        //}
        return points;
    }
    
    private double calcRelativetension (Point2D[] original4P, boolean initial, boolean end) {
        if(initial) {
            double module1 = Math.sqrt(
                    Math.pow(original4P[1].getX() - original4P[0].getX(), 2) + 
                    Math.pow(original4P[1].getY() - original4P[0].getY(), 2));
            double module2 = Math.sqrt(
                    Math.pow(original4P[2].getX() - original4P[1].getX(), 2) + 
                    Math.pow(original4P[2].getY() - original4P[1].getY(), 2));              
                
            double moduleTotal = module1 + module2;
            return moduleTotal * tension / 3;
        }
        if(end) {
            double module2 = Math.sqrt(
                    Math.pow(original4P[2].getX() - original4P[1].getX(), 2) + 
                    Math.pow(original4P[2].getY() - original4P[1].getY(), 2));              
            double module3 = Math.sqrt(
                    Math.pow(original4P[3].getX() - original4P[2].getX(), 2) + 
                    Math.pow(original4P[3].getY() - original4P[2].getY(), 2));              
            double moduleTotal = module2 + module3;
            return moduleTotal * tension / 3;
        }
        double module1 = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(original4P[1].getX() - original4P[0].getX(), 2) + 
                Math.pow(original4P[1].getY() - original4P[0].getY(), 2));
        double module2 = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(original4P[2].getX() - original4P[1].getX(), 2) + 
                Math.pow(original4P[2].getY() - original4P[1].getY(), 2));              
        double module3 = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(original4P[3].getX() - original4P[2].getX(), 2) + 
                Math.pow(original4P[3].getY() - original4P[2].getY(), 2));              
        double moduleTotal = module1 + module2 + module3;
        return moduleTotal * tension / 4;
    }

    
    
    private Point2D calcUnitaryVector(Point2D pOrigin, Point2D pEnd) {
        double module = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pEnd.getX() - pOrigin.getX(), 2) + 
                Math.pow(pEnd.getY() - pOrigin.getY(), 2));
        if (module == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Point2D.Double((pEnd.getX() - pOrigin.getX()) / module, 
                (pEnd.getY() - pOrigin.getY()) /module);
    }   
    
 
    /**
     * Tests this renderer for equality with an arbitrary object.
     *
     * @param obj  the object ({@code null} permitted).
     *
     * @return A boolean.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof XYBezierRenderer)) {
            return false;
        }
        XYBezierRenderer that = (XYBezierRenderer) obj;
        if (this.precision != that.precision) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.fillType != that.fillType) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.gradientPaintTransformer, that.gradientPaintTransformer)) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: To which branch did you add this? Is there an accessible clone of the [tag:jfreechart] repository, perhaps at GitHub? Is there an example or test case? Any reference for the implementation? Going forward, you can submit a pull request [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/pulls).

Comment: @trashgod, Added a pull request to repository. I was the first time and took some time, hope I've done correctly.

Comment: Thank you for pursuing this: [PR#286](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/pull/286).