# XYSplineRenderer goes out of image bounds

Tags: jfreechart

[image]

When I use XYSplineRenderer on `org.jfree:jfreechart` it goes out of the bounds where it renders it...

I tried

```
        XYSplineRenderer splineRenderer = new XYSplineRenderer(15);
        splineRenderer.setDefaultShapesVisible(false);
        plot.setRenderer(splineRenderer);
```

but the graph "glitches" out of the plot...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that reproduces the problem you illustrate; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70021577/230513).

Comment: That's exactly the problem you see there - the "fixes" there didnt help me