# integrating hsqlDB into netbeans 7 IDE

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans-7, hsqldb

I am building a simple desktop application with Java Swing for the front end 
 and use the HyperSQL DB as the database system. I am using the Netbeans 7
 IDE to develop the system.

Is it possible to integrate the HSQLDB into the Netbeans IDE 
 and then be able to connect the application interface to the 
 database?

Will be happy to have a tutorial or article about this.

Comment: Will the user have Netbeans installed?  If not, how is it relevant?

Comment: Sure, what's wrong with normal JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

Create a library entry for your database, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976322/230513) for [H2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/h2/info). Open the `Window > Services > Database` panel to establish properties for a connection and examine the available schemata.