# The import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.OriginalTextAnnotation cannot be resolved

Tags: java, nlp, yelp

I am new to NLP.

I am trying to import: `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.OriginalTextAnnotation`, but I am getting the following error:

`The import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.OriginalTextAnnotation cannot be resolved`

Please let me know which jar file I should use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or directly from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [stanford nlp zip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/stanford/stanford-corenlp.jar.zip) and extract it
2. Add the jar to your project as library

To Add jar as library  in Eclipse go to [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)
To Add jar as library  in Netbeans go to [How to use .jar files in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans)

Comment: @Rookie Did my answer solve your problem ? if yes why don't accept my answer ?