# How to import JSTL core library into my project

Tags: jsp, jstl

I would like to know how I could import the JSTL core library directly into my project instead of accessing it by a link this way:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

EDIT :

In fact it is already working, i have already import the jstl.jar file in my eclipse project. 
I can use  in my jsp files.
The thing is that i would like to use them without having a link to another website. ( http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more how is your project organized? Do you use any build tool/manager?

Comment: Download jar file, then in eclipse open properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add external libraries  , then add your jar file

Comment: Sorry i didn't really elaborate about my question, so i add an "EDIT" part to my first post

Comment: What exactly is your problem with that "link"? It actually isn't a hyperlink orso. It's just an uniform resource identifier. It looks like you somehow think it requires a working internet connection orso (and this is thus NOT true, as said it's just an URI).

Comment: Aaaaah ! Really ? I was thinking it was accessing some data there ! So there is no connection ? What is the use then to put that "uri" to "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" ?

Comment: Just to have an **unique resource identifier**. Just some string that uniquely identifies the desired tag library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the jar file: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstljar.htm
2. Import it into your IDE:

   Eclipse: [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)
      NetBeans: [How to use .jar files in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans)
3. Use an import statement to import your library: import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.*;

Comment: I've already done this thing, i just want it to work in my JSP files without making the link to java.sun.com for using <c:if ... > </c:if>