# ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for ctx

Tags: java, log4j, apache-poi

I have this error when i run my project :

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for ctx
```

Here is the whole stacktrace :

> ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for ctx
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ServiceLoaderUtil
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector.getServiceProviders(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:77)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector.(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:64)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector$ForCopyOnWriteThreadContextMap.(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:211)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createDefaultInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:94)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:71)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.ContextMapLookup.(ContextMapLookup.java:34)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ReflectionUtil.instantiate(ReflectionUtil.java:189)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.(Interpolator.java:81)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.(Interpolator.java:100)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.(AbstractConfiguration.java:135)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.(NullConfiguration.java:32)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.(LoggerContext.java:74)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
> at CreateDocumentSimple.main(CreateDocumentSimple.java:88)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 27 more
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector$ForCopyOnWriteThreadContextMap.(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:211)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createDefaultInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:94)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:71)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ReusableLogEventFactory.(ReusableLogEventFactory.java:42)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.(LoggerConfig.java:101)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.(AbstractConfiguration.java:138)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.(NullConfiguration.java:32)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.(LoggerContext.java:74)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
> at CreateDocumentSimple.main(CreateDocumentSimple.java:88)

I don't know where this come from since i don't user any logger in my whole projet. If you need more information please feel free to ask.

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestPoi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>

        </dependency>
   


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I recall needing `log4j-api-2.17.2.jar`; see the _Component Map_ cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72839258/230513).

Comment: Is the list of dependencies you gave complete? You probably have `log4j-core` version `2.18.0` and `log4j-api` version `2.17.2`. The version of the Log4j2 API must be at least equal to the version of Log4j2 Core.

Answer (score 5):

Add the library log4j-api.jar to the classpath.

To make your project work you have to remove all jars starting with log4j-1.x.

I made the same mistake, because when I downloaded the log4j dependency package, I didn't know which files I needed, so I added all of them. But by doing so, for whatever reason, now log4j 1 is used instead of log4j 2.

Comment: Use maven projects it is easier don't need to download just change dependency code.