# XSSFWorkbook error - Mostly missing some Jar or Dependencies

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am not using Maven, this is a standalone project where i provide the jars in Reference Libraries
The error is thrown when the code is trying to initialize the workbook

```
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Error :

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for ctx
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ServiceLoaderUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector.getServiceProviders(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:77)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector.<clinit>(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:64)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector$ForCopyOnWriteThreadContextMap.<init>(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:211)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createDefaultInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.ContextMapLookup.<init>(ContextMapLookup.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ReflectionUtil.instantiate(ReflectionUtil.java:189)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:81)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:74)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
    at ExcelHandlers.XMLToExcelWriterMessages.initXls(XMLToExcelWriterMessages.java:165)
    at ExcelHandlers.XMLToExcelWriterMessages.getAndReadXml(XMLToExcelWriterMessages.java:56)
    at Core.PICheckerMain.main(PICheckerMain.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 29 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector$ForCopyOnWriteThreadContextMap.<init>(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:211)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createDefaultInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ReusableLogEventFactory.<init>(ReusableLogEventFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.<clinit>(LoggerConfig.java:101)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:74)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
    at ExcelHandlers.XMLToExcelWriterMessages.initXls(XMLToExcelWriterMessages.java:165)
    at ExcelHandlers.XMLToExcelWriterMessages.getAndReadXml(XMLToExcelWriterMessages.java:56)
    at Core.PICheckerMain.main(PICheckerMain.java:133)
```

Below are the jars that i have added, some are for some other stuff, but POI is the problem

[image]

EDIT: Later now i have converted to Maven project and below is the POM file, and error is still same

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>PI</groupId>
  <artifactId>PI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20220320</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post _text_, not _pictures_ of text unless [relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/230513); choose `-lite` _or_ `-full`, not both; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834605/javafx-netbeans-12-4-added-poi-to-library-but-cannot-use-the-import-in-the-proj/72839258#comment128654634_72834605).

Comment: I have log4j in maven dependency now:
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

Comment: It is not clear what POI version you want to use. POI 5.2.2 or POI 4.1.2. I would recommend using POI 5.2.2 with your maven build. Remove the log4j 1.2.17 jar from your build. POI 5.2.2 has dependencies on the jars it needs and maven will pull them in for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the latest version of apache-poi https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/5.2.2 if you are not forced to use a specific version. The latest version of apache-poi does not use log4j anymore, instead log4j-api is used. Link to the latest log4j-api version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.18.0. Due to the security vulnerabilities of the old log4j module, it is recommended to switch to log4j-api anyway. Maybe this also resolves your issue.

Comment: I had log4j-api Missing, i fixed 2 days back, didnt had time to update, thanks anyways :)