# Apache POI Exception with "Could not initialize class …ThemeDocument"

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read Excel. I add poi-ooxml to read Excel from resource.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is my code:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.xlsx")) {
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

It throws exception with

> Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument

I tried to add poi-ooxml-lite but it throws a similar exception about missing DocumentFactory.
Please help me correct if I got anything wrong.

Comment: @trashgod could you specify poi-ooxml plus? I have already used poi-ooxml-full

Comment: To clarify: as noted in the overview cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72839258/230513), use `poi-ooxml` with _either_ `poi-ooxml-lite` _or_ `poi-ooxml-full`, _not both_; as an aside, your exception handler appears to be empty.

Comment: @trashgod I didn't use both poi-ooxml-lite and poi-ooxml-full, I tried it separately. But the exception is same. I remove the exception handler part code since it is not related to this issue.

Comment: I tried reading from a resource stream, but I can't reproduce the effect you describe.